# How to pass long String variable from JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I need to pass long string variable from JavaScript to PHP, but the URL shows me that its too long. I use this method:

```
    function Fillup(id){
     var answer = $('.nicEdit-main').html();
     $.get('submit.php?id='+id+'&answer='+answer,
        function(data){
        $('.answer-div').html(data);
     });
    };
```

And grab them at the PHP file:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $answer = $_GET['answer'];
```

But there are times that `answer` variable are long html codes. For example I created textarea with text editor options, witch you can see is `.nicEdit-main` and if there is picture added, then my variable is too long to be passed trough URL. Can someone please suggest me a better method?

Comment: Better to use jQuery POST instead of GET.

Comment: Use $.post for larger data

Comment: Maybe I can write it to server side text file from JavaScript and then trough PHP open it and read it? And OK will try to use POST.

Comment: @veiss no, its not possible and even if it was, its just more complicated. use `$.post` as suggested and all should be fine

Comment: No, you cannot. Use POST!

Comment: Can someone please give me an example, because I don't realy understand that POST method.

Comment: @veiss, I added one example in answer section, please check if it can help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function Fillup(id){
    var answer = $('.nicEdit-main').html();

    $.post('submit.php',
        {
            id: id,
            answer: answer
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.answer-div').html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

And in PHP side :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
```